# Formatting from python to csv

Tags: python, excel, python-3.x, export-to-csv

I am trying to write keys and values from a dictionary in python to a csv file. I am getting the write output but I want to format it so it does not contain any tabs or spaces. When I try:

```
with open(datafile, 'w', newline='', encoding='utf8') as csvfile:
    datawriter = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter='\t')
    dic = {'2017-03-07': '36939142', '2014-02-19': '13193909'}
    for key in dic.keys():
        date = key
        order_number = dic[key]
        row = [date, order_number]
        datawriter.writerow(','.join(row))
```

I am looking for the output in the csv file to look like. 2017-03-07, 36939142. But instead in outputs this:    2   0   1   7   -   0   3   -   0   7 and the order number 3    6   9   3   9   1   4   2.

With spaces/tabs in between each character. This makes it impossible to use many of the excel functions.

How can I get the expected output in the csv file?

Comment: The `writerow` function takes a list as an argument, not a string. Just change to `datawriter.writerow(row)`.

Comment: @JordanSinger is correct, but just changing that portion would result in columns being separated with tabs, not commas. `delimter` has to be changed to `','` as well as changing the function call of `writerow` to pass a list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is in the `delimiter` and the parameter with which you call `writerow()`. `csv` module already handles delimiting your columns for you, so you don't need to format your row with `','.join(row)`. What happened in your code was that you passed a string `'2017-03-07,36939142'` into the function `writerow()` which expects a list (as mentioned by @JordanSinger) . So then it took the string and cast it into a list, which becomes `['2', '0', '1', '7', '-', etc]`. Then the delimiter was a `'\t'`, so the csv writer took each character of your string created from the `','.join(row)` and put a tab in between every character (as if each char is its own column, separated by tabs). So you want to change your delimiter as well as change the function call to `writerow` to pass a list, not a string.

Also, you can cut down the code by unpacking your dictionary into tuples of `(key, value)` pairs instead of iterating through the keys.

```
dic = {'2017-03-07': '36939142', '2014-02-19': '13193909'}

with open(datafile, 'w', newline='', encoding='utf8') as csvfile:
    datawriter = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=',')
    for date,order_number in dic.items():
        datawriter.writerow([date,order_number])
```

Output:

```
2017-03-07,36939142
2014-02-19,13193909
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
with open(datafile, 'w', newline='', encoding='utf8') as csvfile:
    datawriter = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=',')
    dic = {'2017-03-07': '36939142', '2014-02-19': '13193909'}

    for key, value in dic.items():
        row = [key, value]
        datawriter.writerow(row)
```